# HIBERNATE Throwing ERROR:"a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session ", while Updating the object

Tags: java, hibernate, session

while updating the Object it is unable to update throwing the above ERROR

```
PublishedAssessmentData associatepublishobj = (PublishedAssessmentData) associatePublishedobjectdata.get(i);                  
PublishedAssessmentData existing_publishobj = service.transferupdatedpublishedassessments(associatepublishobj,sbipublishobj);                     
openSession.saveOrUpdate(existing_publishobj);
```

Comment: In simple words: Multiple objects (different object ID), of same type, having same ID (PK) are associated to your session. So when you do, `session.saveOrUpdate(obj)`, Hibernate is unable to decide which object it should save/update.

Answer (score 0):

Only reason could be, You got object from Hibernate and than again trying to saveOrUpdate.
You was saved object in Session previously and you are trying to save it again.

call commit on the session from which you that object associates or got.

Comment: @Arshad I am commiting whatever the object i save in session i think problem is not that....

Comment: @SanthoshKumar544 if you calls save on an object which already associate with a session, you will definately have an exception while committing. BTW what is class of Exception ?

Comment: @YahyaArshad In that case you will possibly get constraint violation exception but not the above mentioned exception.